# The Apple ID you entered couldn't be found or your password was incorrect. Please try again. | In-App Purchase

Tags: itunes, apple-id, password, in-app-purchase

I bought an In-App Purchase yesterday. While buying the app crashed, so I tried to restore the purchase (money was already taken from my account). But if I'm entering my correct Apple-ID password (works when logging in into iTunes), it says:

> The Apple ID you entered couldn't be found or your password was incorrect. Please try again.

When I'm entering a wrong password, it just says:

> Your Apple ID or password is incorrect

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Contact the developer, if no solution ask for a refund via https://reportaproblem.apple.com/

Comment: The App Store is doing this when you try to upgrade